# Proper Linux-based internet usage monitor

Tags: linux, ubuntu, internet, network-monitoring, resource-usage

Anyone knows a Linux-based internet usage monitor that is decent, and up to date?

- I found an up to date one, Download Monitor, but that's tied up to Ubuntu Unity App.
- I found an up to date doc, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMonitorInternetTrafficTotals, last updated 2013-03-18, but the first option, ipac-ng, is no longer in the current Debian/Ubuntu repos.

I hope there is still a program out there that,

- Not tied up to a specific DM (e.g., Ubuntu Unity)
- Able to gauge only the internet usage, not all traffic going through eth0 (e.g., local network).  I.e., to ignore LAN traffic but only monitor internet usage

Is there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one that is closest to my requirement:

Package: bwm-ng
Priority: optional
Description-en: small and simple console-based bandwidth monitor
 Bandwidth Monitor NG is a small and simple console-based live bandwidth
 monitor.
 .
 Short list of features:

- supports /proc/net/dev, netstat, getifaddr, sysctl, kstat and
  libstatgrab
- unlimited number of interfaces supported
- interfaces are added or removed dynamically from list
- white-/blacklist of interfaces
- output of KB/s, Kb/s, packets, errors, average, max and total sum
- output in curses, plain console, CSV or HTML
- configfile

Homepage: http://www.gropp.org/?id=projects&sub=bwm-ng
Origin: Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

For something incredibly lightweight, take a look at [**nettop**](http://www.sourcefiles.org/Networking/Tools/Scripts/nettop-0.2.3.tar.gz).  This little command line program is basically **top** (shows CPU usage) for networks.  One caveat is that you must run it as root, but you can invoke it like this:

```
$ sudo nettop -i **device**
```

where you replace `**device**` with whatever your network device is.  Typically, it will be `eth0` or `wlan0`.

It will break your traffic up by usage, with the top line (labelled `total`) showing the total bandwidth being consumed.

Comment: I don't think it can filter traffic by subnet, however.

Comment: Thanks you! as you have spotted that it can only gauge all traffic going through eth0, not just usage out to/from the internet.